# how to retrieve email credentials from database in laravel?

Tags: laravel

i allow the admin to change the email credentials dynamically in database so now how to retriev it .env file to send email.

```
MAIL_DRIVER={{config('settings.mail_driver')}}
MAIL_HOST={{config('settings.mail_host')}}
MAIL_PORT={{config('settings.mail_port')}}
MAIL_USERNAME={{config('settings.mail_username')}}
MAIL_PASSWORD={{config('settings.mail_password')}}
MAIL_ENCRYPTION={{config('settings.mail_encryption')}}
```

it does not working so please tell me the proper method of retrieving it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this before, I created a new service provider `MailServiceProvider` and in there I set the `mail` config with

```
public function boot() {
    $mail = // get value in DB
    config(['mail.driver'=> $mail->driver]);
    config(['mail.host'=>$mail->host]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config/app.php

```
'mail_driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER')
```

In you .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER= what ever value you want here
```

Then to call it anywhere

```
{{config('app.mail_driver')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not good idea to changes `.env` dynamically but still if you want to it you can try this option.

```
 public static function changeEnvironmentVariable($key,$value)
{
 $path = base_path('.env');

if(is_bool(env($key)))
{
    $old = env($key)? 'true' : 'false';
}
elseif(env($key)===null){
    $old = 'null';
}
else{
    $old = env($key);
}

if (file_exists($path)) {
    file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
        "$key=".$old, "$key=".$value, file_get_contents($path)
    ));
}
}
```

You have to pass `$key` variable name and it`s value in`$value`.

Comment: from where to pass $key  and $value ,and where to place this function in MailController or in mail.php file.

Comment: Anywhere before you want to actually change your values. It's a function so so can place it in any file.

Comment: and then there will be a need to write credentials in .env file or not?

Comment: @RafiUllah above code is actually writing `credentials ` in `.env` file.